# Как сравнить несколько аргументов?

Tags: linux, bash

На вход передаются 3 аргумента: `Ivanov Ivan 777`. Хочу проверить - совпадают ли он с тем что внутри кода. Накатал скрипт. Сравнение некорректно отрабатывает

```
#!/bin/bash

checkData() {

if [["$1"=="Ivanov" && "$2"=="Ivan" && $3=="777" ]]; then
    return 0 
  else
    return 1
  fi
  
}

if checkData $1 $2 $3 then
 echo 'ok'
    else
 echo 'error'
 fi
```

Comment: Чем вас не устроил diff?

Comment: Тут больше вопрос в прокачке навыков баша) Задача взята по мере необходимости

Comment: понял вас! (еще 5 символов)

Comment: `[[ "$1" == "Ivanov" && "$2" == "Ivan" && $3 == "777" ]]` пробелы расставьте

Comment: @PotroNik не пашет

Comment: @Radzhab, в итоге то у вас получилось реализовать функцию?

Comment: @PotroNik оказывается надо было через bash запускать а не sh

Comment: Если избавиться от башизмов, то можно на любом шелле запускать. Башизмы — это часто плохо,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо добавить пробелы до и после скобок и равенством. также не хватает `;` после условии IF

```
#!/bin/bash

checkData() {

if [[ "$1"=="Ivanov" && "$2"=="Ivan" && $3=="777" ]]; then
    return 0 
  else
    return 1
fi
  
}

if checkData $1 $2 $3; then
 echo 'ok'
    else
 echo 'error'
 fi
```

```
➜ ./s.sh Ivanov Ivan 77
error
➜ ./s.sh Ivanov Ivan 777
ok
```

Comment: У меня во всех случаях выдаёт ок

Comment: какая версия баша у вас? `/bin/bash --version`

Comment: `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` - если пробелы в сравнении не расставить, то всегда ОК возвращает

Comment: хм. может потому, что у меня `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20`